# Matlab - Frechet algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, similarity, curve, coupling

I am new to Matlab. Pardon lack of details or question clarity.
I used Frechet distance calculation algorithm implemented using Matlab to obtain similarity between curves (2 sets of X,Y data) and I have the results.

Question: Is it possible to obtain the second set of (X,Y) data based on the first set of (X,Y) data and the Frechet distance and coupling sequence?

Many thanks

Detail:

**Sample input:**

matrix1 = (t, f1(t))

matrix2 = (t, f2(t))

**Calculation:**

```
[frechetVal, couplingVals] = FrechetDistanceCal(matrix1,matrix2,dfcn)
```

where

I have used a standard discrete-frechet distance algorithm (Not at liberty to share)

and

```
dfcn = @(matrix1,matrix2) sqrt(sum( (matrix1-matrix2).^2 ));
```

**Sample output:**

frechetVal = 0.0365

couplingVals = 1 1

**Question:** 
Given frechetVal , couplingVals and matrix1, is it possible to get matrix2?

Comment: You should be more specifiy and include some code (a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Luis Mendo, I have added some details. Is this better?

Comment: @user2013  That is better.  We can definitely try to help, but maybe the math site is better.  :/

Answer (score 0):

The best that you're going to be able to do is to approximate `matrix2`, by assembling for each time the coupled point from `matrix1`. The value of `frechetVal` will tell you the maximum distance that a point was moved.

Comment: Thank you. Re-assembling using the coupling is what I don't understand - How's that done? Any resource you know of that I can use to understand or would you be able to explain a bit?

Comment: @user2013 It's hard to say without access to the documentation of your Frechet distance routine.